# How do I add multiple if possibilities?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm fairly new to C# and would like help adding more if possibilities. If this doesn't make sense, here is the code:

```
if (flatTextBox1.Text == "XeC2YfjcEtzD6Kw7zkCssjDgoRmdZcv8")                
{
    MessageBox.Show("Enjoy Goat Hub! Credits to oreo #####");
    this.Hide();
    Form3 form3 = new Form3();
    Form3 main = form3;
    main.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Key or Key Copied Incorrectly");
}
```

I want             `if (flatTextBox1.Text == "XeC2YfjcEtzD6Kw7zkCssjDgoRmdZcv8")`
           to be equal to multiple things. So if a user enters any of those 2 possiblities in the text box, it will let them access form 3.

Comment: Did you mean using an [if-else if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) statement? Eg `if (flattextbox1.text == "test 1") { ... } else if (flattextbox1.text == "test 2") { ... }`

Comment: Did you mean something like this? `if (flatTextBox1.Text == "FirstValue" || flatTextBox1.Text == "SecondValue") { ... }`

Comment: `if (flatTextBox1.Text == "string1" || flatTextBox1.Text == "string2")`?

Comment: You mean an OR- statement? As in `f.Text=="a" || f.Text=="b"`? Your question is very difficult to read. Please be short, clear, and to the point.

Comment: I did not understand the question. What do you mean by `I want " if (flatTextBox1.Text == "XeC2YfjcEtzD6Kw7zkCssjDgoRmdZcv8") " to be equal to multiple things.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array of strings outside of the scope, and check if the array contains their answer:

```
public string[] answers = {"XeC2YfjcEtzD6Kw7zkCssjDgoRmdZcv8", "test", "test2"};
```

And then in your method:

```
if(answers.Contains(textBox1.Text)) {
    MessageBox.Show("Enjoy Goat Hub! Credits to oreo #####");
    this.Hide();
    Form3 form3 = new Form3();
    Form3 main = form3;
    main.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var keys = {
    "XeC2YfjcEtzD6Kw7zkCssjDgoRmdZcv8",
    "...",
    "...",
    "etc"
};
if (!keys.Contains(flatTextBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Key or Key Copied Incorrectly");
    return; 
}

// If you make it here it's a success
//   and we've saved a level of indentation.
```

Even better if you handle the comparison in a database or web service. If the keys are embedded in the code a clever person **will** be able to find them.

I also recommend abstracting this to it's own method (which will also make moving this to a DB/web service a little later much easier):

```
bool IsValidKey(string input)
{
    var keys = {
        "XeC2YfjcEtzD6Kw7zkCssjDgoRmdZcv8",
        "...",
        "...",
        "etc"
    };
    return keys.Contains(input);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
if (!IsValidKey(flatTextBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Key or Key Copied Incorrectly");
    return; 
}
//success
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for an OR clause in your if statement. E.g.

```
if (flatTextBox1.Text == "XeC2YfjcEtzD6Kw7zkCssjDgoRmdZcv8" || flatTextBox1.Text == "something else")
```

N.B This is a simple example. Once you get beyond one or two values you might want to use something like a List or array and check if the textbox content matches any of the items from the list

Answer (score 1):

ThePerplexedOne posted what is probably a better option for implementing this, but here is another option:

You do this by adding either a "||" for an OR condition, or "&&" for an AND condition.

In your case, you would do something like:

```
    if (flatTextBox1.Text == "XeC2YfjcEtzD6Kw7zkCssjDgoRmdZcv8" || 
flatTextBox1.Text == "myTest" || flatTextBox1.Text == "otherText")

        {
        MessageBox.Show("Enjoy Goat Hub! Credits to oreo #####");
        this.Hide();
        Form3 form3 = new Form3();
        Form3 main = form3;
        main.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Key or Key Copied Incorrectly");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (flatTextBox1.Text == "XeC2YfjcEtzD6Kw7zkCssjDgoRmdZcv8" || flatTextBox1.Text == "5s5dgGs55as4g4d844adsgd")
     {
                    MessageBox.Show("Enjoy Goat Hub! Credits to oreo #####");
                    this.Hide();
                    Form3 form3 = new Form3();
                    form3.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Key or Key Copied Incorrectly");
                }
```

or

```
if (new string[] { "XeC2YfjcEtzD6Kw7zkCssjDgoRmdZcv8", "5s5dgGs55as4g4d844adsgd" }.Contains(flatTextBox1.Text))
                {  
                MessageBox.Show("Enjoy Goat Hub! Credits to oreo #####");
                this.Close();
                Form3 form3 = new Form3();
                form3.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Key or Key Copied Incorrectly");
                }
```